# How to get a list of all topics containing specific values known to MQTT broker?

Tags: mqtt, wildcard, distributed-system, paho

I'm looking for a way to get a list of all topics known to a broker. There are some quite similar question's, but they didn't help me to figure it out for my use case. 
 
I've got 3 Raspberry Pi's with multiple sensors (temperature, humidity) which are connected over an MQTT network. Every Pi has it's own database containing time series of measurements and other system variables(like CPU). 
 
Now I'm looking for a way for the following szenario:

I want to monitor my system and detect anomalies. For that I want to get all sensor-time series in the last x seconds and process them in a python script. My system to do the monitoring calculations can be every Pi. 
 
**Example:** I'm on RPI2 and want to monitor the whole distributed network. There's no given knowledge about the sensors attached to the Pi's. Now from my python script running on RP2 I would initalise a MQTT client and subscribe every sensor data on the broker. 
 I know about the wildcard # but I'm not sure how to use it in that case. My magic command would look like the following pseudo code:

```
1) client subscribe to all sensor data - #/sensor/#
2) get list with all topics 
3) client subscribe to all topics from given list list/#
4) analyse data for anomalies every x seconds
```

[image: Distributed Network with broker and sensors]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your wildcard topic patterns are not valid. Topic patterns can only contain a single '#' character and it can only appear at the end of a topic e.g. `foo/bar/#` is valid, `#/foo` is not. You can use the `+` character which is a single level wildcard character.

This means a topic pattern of `+/sensor/#` will match each of the following:

- `rpi1/sensor/foo`
- `rpi1/sensor/bar/temp`

but not

- `rpi1/foo/sensor/bar`

Next brokers do not have a list of topics that exist. Topics only really exist at the instant that a message is published to one, the broker then checks the patterns that subscribing clients have requested and checks that topic against the list and delivers it to the clients that match.

Thirdly when bridging brokers in loops like that you have to be very careful with the  bridge filters to make sure that messages don' end up a constant loop.

The solution is probably to designate a "master" broker and bridge all the others one way to that broker and then have the client subscribe to either '#' to get everything or something more like '+/sensor/#' to just see the sensor readings.

Comment: Ok I understand, thank you! So If I understand correctly I have to subscribe to the correct sensor-topic to get the measurements of that sensor. But I have no chance to get the topics without someone else subscribing to them and making them publish their measurements without knowing about the exact topics hierarchy and message the sensor needs to start publishing its measurements. Is that correct?

Comment: If you subscribe to `#` then you will see every (assuming no ACLs are in place) messages published. There is no need for anybody else to have subscribed.

Comment: So I just tested the whole set up and if I subscribe to `#` I'm only able to see messages if a sensor reading is requested. But that means If I use my system as blackbox where I want to be able to subscribe to all topics by `#` and afterwards find out about the topics it cant work that way around because I need someone else to trigger a sensor reading and make the sensor publish that reading to get the measurements from my subscribtion.

Comment: If your sensors only publish on request then there is no way to make this work as a black box. The only workaround would be if the sensors published with the retained flag set to true

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your efford! Seems like I have to change some of my plans.